# How to run a command in neovim's terminal mode without leaving this mode

Tags: neovim, terminal

Suppose `ALT+h` to mapped to `<C-\><C-N><C-w>j` as following [Nvim documentation: nvim_terminal_emulator](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html). We have two horizontally split windows with terminal buffers and the right window is activated.

After hitting `ATL+h`, the left window will be activated but the right window will be switched to normal mode automatically. Is it possible to let the right window stay in terminal mode for neovim? Or does neovim has equivalent [terminal-typing](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-typing) which allows us to not leave the terminal mode.

Answer (score 3):

`:h <Cmd>` pseudokey is answers this problem:

```
tnoremap <alt-h> <Cmd>wincmd h<CR>
tnoremap <alt-j> <Cmd>wincmd j<CR>
tnoremap <alt-k> <Cmd>wincmd k<CR>
tnoremap <alt-l> <Cmd>wincmd l<CR>
```

Also see `:help <Cmd>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But sometimes I don't want to re-enter terminal-insert mode automatically. For example after running a large test suite in neovim's terminal, I need to go back and forth between test output and source code to find out why some tests failed. When switching back to the test output, I want to check the output in the middle of the screen but `startinsert` will automatically scroll the screen to bottom. The problem for neovim is in order to run a command in terminal-insert mode, we have to leave this terminal-insert mode via `<C-\><C-N>` first.

Comment: Considering we can run a command in insert mode without leaving insert mode, for example, `<C-r> REGISTER` to paste some text from a register, it doesn't make sense we have to leave terminal-insert mode first to run a command.

Comment: This is reported as a bug [tnoremap <Cmd>wincmd doesn't preserve mode · Issue #12246 · neovim/neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12246) on github. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @Coiby Note that the issue is about Neovim-specific `<cmd>`. `<c-\><c-n>` should and will work the way it does.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear enough. What I mean is that `<Cmd>` is supposed to be the answer to my question but the aforementioned bug makes it impossible to "stay in terminal-insert mode" after running a command.

Comment: @Coiby that bug you've linked was fixed however it still doesn't work for me, even in neovim's v0.5.0 / stable / nightly build. Did you ever find a solution to your original question? I had a script to retain terminal mode properly but it only works in Vim. For some reason, neovim doesn't work.

Comment: @ColinKennedy Sorry for the late reply. I eventually switch to vim after implementing https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6290

Comment: As of https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/957cf67d50516ba98716f59c9e1cb6412ec1535d the `<Cmd>` form is not specific to nvim.